# How to get child nodes in documentFragment?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I need to know if there is a "span" in my extracted content.

Simple js part, getting selection from textarea:

```
...
selection = this.getWin().getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
content = selection.extractContents();
alert(content)// this gets documentFragment
alert(content.firstChild)//null
fontEl = document.createElement ("span")
fontEl.appendChild(content);
alert(fontEl.outerHTML)// works ok. but now i have 2 spans if there was one before append
```

there is my jsfiddle. i test changing the font-size. it works, but it is spamming spans because of this problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/DCGRg/73/

Comment: If the DocumentFragment's `firstChild` is null then there are no children, same as any other node.

Comment: but if html fragment is: <div class="myclass">test</div>? Should firstChild return div then?

Comment: I seem to have downvoted, although I didn't intend to and have no memory of doing so, and there is no sign of a -1 in my reputation history. If you edit your question then I can remove my apparent downvote.

Comment: Downvote removed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't far off. Here's an updated demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DCGRg/73/

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
var font_size = combo.getValue();
var selection = this.getWin().getSelection();
if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var content = range.extractContents();
    var fontEl = this.getWin().document.createElement("span");
    fontEl.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';
    fontEl.appendChild(content);
    range.insertNode(fontEl);
    selection.selectAllChildren(fontEl);
}
```

Comment: but it's spamming a lot of empty html tags. how can i fix it?

Comment: p.s. thanks, even though it's better then mine, but i need to fix spamming tags over the text. Check "HTML SOURCE" button to see. Button is the second one from the right.

Comment: @Feanor: That's trickier. You'll need a more subtle approach, involving interacting more closely with the DOM. It's non-trivial.